# Where was The Murray, South Australia?

Tags: 19th-century, vital-records, australia, south-australia

My 2nd great grandparents Edward Sleep and Charlotte Hancock had their first child William Joseph born on 29 Dec 1854 in South Australia.

The Place of Registration (Page: 207 Volume: 6) was given as The Murray, South Australia.

Being from South Australia originally, I am familiar with the River Murray (or Murray River) and places like Murray Bridge, but I have not been able to determine where "The Murray" would be.  Presumably it was the name of a registration office (and not necessarily a locality in its own right) but was it in a town called The Murray or in another named locality?

---

As commented by @ColeValleyGirl [The Murray was an electoral district](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_district_of_The_Murray_%28South_Australia%29).  However, this was only from 1857 to 1862 i.e. a few years after this birth was registered.  Consequently, I do not think this will be the answer, because I suspect that it would have encompassed a very large area.

---

Source:

*Ancestry.com. Australia, Birth Index, 1788-1922 [database on-line]. Provo, UT, USA: Ancestry.com Operations, Inc., 2010.*

Comment: It was an electoral district http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_district_of_The_Murray_%28South_Australia%29

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl That link is useful but because it appears that "The Murray" was also used as the name of an electoral district but only from 1857-1862 which is 2-3 years after the time this birth was registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Murray was a [registration district](http://www.jaunay.com/district.html) from 1848 to 1856, being renamed Burra in that year.

According to this [discussion](http://archiver.rootsweb.ancestry.com/th/read/AUS-SAGEN/2001-01/0980806369), "In 1848, The Murray was proclaimed as a Registration District with its
Registry Office located in Kooringa, the centre of a growing mining area."

Comment: Thanks for those links which I had not seen. The info makes perfect sense because their next child was born at Kooringa in 1856.